# Do browsers have to "render" (for lack of a better term) divs that have the display:none property?

Tags: css, browser, render

If I have, for instance:

```
<div style="display:none">
    (The content of this div is a huge QuickTime movie.)
</div>
<div>
    (The content of this div is just lines of text.)
</div>
```

Will the browser try to start downloading the QT movie in the first div?

I tried searching this site and Google before asking, so if it's been answered before and my Google-Fu is just off today, I sincerely apologize. It seems like a question that would have been asked, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: Loading content isn't the same as rendering.

Comment: Or, as another example for clarification, if the first div contained a bunch of pictures, will the browser download all these pictures to it's cache?

Comment: You may or may not have noticed the "(for lack of a better term)" in the question itself. I am (or, was) unaware of what the proper term, apparently "loading content", might be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything with a `<div>` that is set to `display:none` is still technically and semantically there. Any content contained within the hidden `<div>` will be loaded as if it were visible.